# bash - easy way to replace directory string from right-hand side

Tags: regex, string, bash, awk, sed

I'm wondering if there's a easy way to handle this question: find one pattern from the right-hand side of a string, and then replace the right side of it.
For example:

```
PATTERN='bin'
REPLACE_TO='dev/zero'
STRING='/bin/bash/bin/test/test1.txt'
```

We found the last index of PATTERN in STRING is 2, and then replace it with REPLACE_TO. So the result is:

```
STRING='bin/bash/dev/zero'
```

I know I can write a function to do that, not sure if there's a east way which uses sed/awk/others to make it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
PATTERN='bin'
REPLACE_TO='dev/zero'
STRING='/bin/bash/bin/test/test1.txt'
echo "${STRING%$PATTERN*}$REPLACE_TO"

/bin/bash/dev/zero
```

`${STRING%$PATTERN*}` will remove right hand side of `$STRING` that starts with `$PATTERN`.

Answer (score 0):

With sed:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATTERN='bin'
REPLACE_TO='dev/zero'
STRING='/bin/bash/bin/test/test1.txt'

#Escape PATTERN and REPLACE_TO
PATTERN=$(sed -e 's/[][\/&*?+.^${}]/\\&/g' <<< "$PATTERN")
REPLACE_TO=$(sed -e 's/[][\/&*?+.^${}]/\\&/g' <<< "$REPLACE_TO")

sed -r "s/(.*)$PATTERN.*/\1$REPLACE_TO/" <<< "$STRING"
```

If PATTERN isn't present then the output is STRING